# Rails/SQL statement subtracting a null value

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

Hey all i am using this query within a rails app. I am trying to find the number of unique employees, so i created one query that will find out how many `total_employees` there are and then one that figures out how many `duplicates` there are(`duplicates` are worked out using an `id_number`). Then i subtract the `duplicates` from the `total_employees` giving me the number of unique individuals. the `id_number` field is not compulsory, so `id_number`'s that are null should be not included with the count.

The problem is that when i try run the query if the `duplicates` is null the number of `unique_employees` will become null aswell.

here is my query

```
     SELECT SUM(total_count.count) - SUM(duplicate_count.count) as unique_employees, SUM(total_count.count), SUM(duplicate_count.count)
   FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(1) as count
        FROM participants
        JOIN training_programs
          ON training_programs.id = participants.training_program_id
        WHERE training_programs.category IN ('B', 'C', 'D')
          AND training_programs.skills_development_id = 123
          AND participants.foreign = FALSE
          AND participants.race = 'African'
          AND participants.gender = 'Male'
          AND participants.employed = true
      ) as total_count,
      (SELECT SUM(count) as count
      FROM (SELECT COUNT(id_number)-1 AS count
        FROM participants
        JOIN training_programs
          ON training_programs.id = participants.training_program_id
        WHERE training_programs.category IN ('B', 'C', 'D')
          AND training_programs.skills_development_id = 123
          AND participants.foreign = FALSE
          AND participants.race = 'African'
          AND participants.gender = 'Male'
          AND participants.employed = true
          AND participants.id_number <> ''
        GROUP BY id_number
        HAVING COUNT(id_number) > 1) as duplicated_records
      ) as duplicate_count
```

so i am getting this

[image: query_results]

My SQL foo is not the best in the world so i am trying to figure out how to get all null values to be seen as 0. I would also like to have this within a single query since it is run in a loop and will have to be re-run a few dozen times per save depending on the input given.

or any help with the above would be great. Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

If i was to add a duplicate the query runs fine. so the query is good just that if there are no duplicates then no matter the number of total_empolyees the query will return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just surround all values that can potentially yield null in `IFNULL`

```
SUM(IFNULL(duplicate_count.count,0))
```

Comment: Dude that was exactly what i was looking for! Thank you so much. i was hitting this wall all day long

Comment: I edited the question name to reflect the actual problem i was having.